# Ultra-low latency programming on Linux, where to begin?

Tags: c, linux, latency

I heard there are some ways to modify linux such that an particular application can obtain very low latency such that whenver it ask resources, the OS will try to give it the resource as soon as possible, kind of overriding the default preemptive multitasking mechanism, I dont have a CS background, but the application I am working-on is very latency-sensitive, can anyone tell me are there any docs/stuff on this specific matter? many thanks.

Comment: Set the scheduler to `SCHED_FIFO`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Or `SCHED_RR` ?

Answer (score 4):

Guaranteed low-latency response is called the **real time** capability. It means that timing goals that are realistic are guaranteed to be met.

There is a project for it called RTLinux. See the Real-Time Linux Wiki: https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

There are two real time models :

- soft real time system - you get it by applying [RT preempt kernel patches](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RT_PREEMPT_HOWTO). I think it guaranties context switch within 10 ms. The goal of this project is to conform to hard real time requirements
- hard real time system - have stricter guaranties (response of 1 ms). There are some libraries (like [xenomai](http://www.xenomai.org/)) that claim they provide hard real time system.

Comment: this is wrong - hard realtime is describing processes where a missed deadline is a system failure, while soft realtime means that a missed deadline is only a degradation of the system state. It has nothing to do with actual time intervals